# Image background according the size of the screen without using nine patch

Tags: android, image, background, nine-patch

I have an image background like the first image of squareup image: https://market.android.com/details?id=com.squareup.cardcase&hl=fr

I need to display this image background in the screen (fill_parent) in every size of screen.

How can I do? I can't use nine patch due to geometric issue of the image. Do I need to make the image in all the size?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In code (rather than via the layout XML) you can create a bitmap of the right aspect ratio (device height x width) by cropping the image after scaling the bitmap to be big enough to crop. You need to make sure that the image can be scaled up/down (preferably down) without losing sharpness. You also need to be sure that important information will not be lost when the image is cropped with different aspect ratios.

Once you have the resulting bitmap then place it on the display as an ImageView's content.

I find that it is better to size logos separately from underlying images and layer image views on on top of each other so that the text remains crisp.

I created a subclass of the ImageView class to encapsulate the resizing and cropping. The only method of value is the overridden onMeasure() method:

```
/**
 * Override the onMeasure method to resize the Bitmap as needed
 */
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);


    Drawable currentDrawable = this.getDrawable();
    BitmapDrawable theBitmapDrawable;
    if (BitmapDrawable.class.isInstance(currentDrawable)){
        // We have a bitmap to work with
        theBitmapDrawable = (BitmapDrawable) currentDrawable;
        Bitmap currentBitmap = theBitmapDrawable.getBitmap();
        Bitmap resizedBitmap = null;

        if (currentBitmap != null) {
            int currentHeight = currentBitmap.getHeight();
            int currentWidth = currentBitmap.getWidth();
            int parentWidth = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
            int parentHeight = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
            if ((currentHeight != parentHeight) || (currentWidth != parentWidth)) {
                // The bitmap needs to be resized, and/or cropped to fit
                if ((currentHeight < parentHeight) || (currentWidth < parentWidth)) {
                    // Need to make the bitmap larger
                    float heightFactor = (float) parentHeight / (float) currentHeight;
                    float widthFactor = (float) parentWidth / (float) currentWidth;
                    float scaleFactor;
                    // Choose the largest factor
                    if (Float.compare(heightFactor, widthFactor) < 0) {
                        scaleFactor = widthFactor;
                    } else {
                        scaleFactor = heightFactor;
                    }
                    int dstWidth = (int) (currentWidth * scaleFactor);
                    int dstHeight = (int) (currentHeight * scaleFactor);
                    if (dstWidth < parentWidth) dstWidth = parentWidth;     // Deal with off by one rounding errors
                    if (dstHeight < parentHeight) dstHeight = parentHeight; // Deal with off by one rounding errors
                    resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(currentBitmap, dstWidth, dstHeight, true);
                    currentBitmap.recycle();
                } else if ((currentHeight > parentHeight) && (currentWidth > parentWidth)){
                    // Need to make the splash screen bitmap smaller
                    float heightFactor = (float) parentHeight / (float) currentHeight;
                    float widthFactor = (float) parentWidth / (float) currentWidth;
                    float scaleFactor;
                    // Choose the largest factor
                    if (Float.compare(heightFactor, widthFactor) < 0) {
                        scaleFactor = widthFactor;
                    } else {
                        scaleFactor = heightFactor;
                    }
                    int dstWidth = (int) (currentWidth * scaleFactor);
                    int dstHeight = (int) (currentHeight * scaleFactor);
                    if (dstWidth < parentWidth) dstWidth = parentWidth;     // Deal with off by one rounding errors
                    if (dstHeight < parentHeight) dstHeight = parentHeight; // Deal with off by one rounding errors
                    resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(currentBitmap, dstWidth, dstHeight, true);
                    currentBitmap.recycle();
                } else {
                    // No need to resize the image - we'll just need to crop it
                    resizedBitmap = currentBitmap;
                }

                // Now crop the image so that it fits the aspect ratio of the screen
                currentHeight = resizedBitmap.getHeight();
                currentWidth = resizedBitmap.getWidth();
                Bitmap newBitmap;
                if ((currentHeight != parentHeight) || (currentWidth != parentWidth)) {
                    // Crop the image to fit exactly
                    int startX = (currentWidth - parentWidth)/2;
                    if (startX < 0) startX = 0; // Hmm!
                    int startY = (currentHeight - parentHeight)/2;
                    if (startY < 0) startY = 0; // Hmm! again
                    newBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(resizedBitmap, startX, startY, parentWidth, parentHeight);
                    resizedBitmap.recycle();
                } else {
                    // The resized image is the exact right size
                    newBitmap = resizedBitmap;
                }

                this.setImageBitmap(newBitmap);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: @user420574 - you need to extend the ImageView class as in `public class WidgetSelfSizingImageView extends ImageView {`